# How would I create an object that passes the average as an argument to the function and get the return value to print out? I haven't coded for a bit

Tags: python

Error is saying grade isn't defined and I don't know how to define it. I googled a bunch but I don't think the information helped much. Or at least it didn't click in my brain... I appreciate the help.

```
class ClassGrader:

    earnedTotal = 0.0
    Total = 0.0
    grade = Grade()
                  
    while 'earned' != 'exit':
        earned = input("What is the grade earned? or type *exit* to proceed to the next section: ")
    
        if earned == 'exit':
        
            while 'subTotal' != 'exit':
                subTotal = input("What is the total of assignment? Enter the next... or type *exit* for the average grade: ")
            
                if subTotal == 'exit':
                
                    average = earnedTotal/Total
                    
                    print("The average of "+str(earnedTotal)+"/"+str(Total)+" is "+str(average*100)) + grade.Grade(average)
                    exit()

                else:
                    Total=float(subTotal)+Total
                    print(Total)
    
        else:
            earnedTotal=float(earned)+earnedTotal
            print(earnedTotal)
```

```
def Grade(i):
                  
    if i >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif i >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif i >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif i >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"
```

Comment: Is `Grade` a class that contains a `Grade()` method? Since it's a little confusing that you're using `grade = Grade()` alongside `grade.Grade(average)`. Since the definition of `Grade` you showed is just a method that returns a string, there's no way its returned value would have a `Grade()` method. Did you mean to just do `Grade(average)`? Also, you have `print(something) + grade.Grade(average)`, which doesn't make sense since the grade isn't within the print statement. Did you mean to do something like `print(something + Grade(average))`?

Comment: Too many errors to really help you here. Variables being quoted, or not being used after input, or being conjured out of nowhere... for example `average` is only ever claculated as `0.0/0.0` which isn't going to be useful

Comment: @RandomDavis - I used to do Java coding and I am clearly confused. I shall make it prettier on my end but would I "print(something + Grade(average))" to get the letter grade average?

Comment: @RandomDavis 
    print("The average of "+str(earnedTotal)+"/"+str(Total)+" is "+str(average*100)) + Grade(average)
NameError: name 'Grade' is not defined
>>> 
This is what I receive as an error. I don't understand why it is undefined.

Comment: @Joffan When I remove the quotations I get a variable undefined error. And the average does work for the float() method changes the input value and holds a float value that keeps adding until the loop is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did have many, many problems here, not the least of which is unclear requirements.  What you have here should be functions, not classes.  You are confused between variables and strings.  Here is something that mostly does what I THINK you want.

As a user experience thing, it's not fair to require them to type the whole word "exit" to stop the process.  One mistake, and this will crash converting the string to float.  You should just have them press "enter" and check for an empty string.  I haven't done that here.

```
def Grade(avg):
    return "FFFFFFDCBAA"[int(avg*10)]

def ClassGrader():
    earnedTotal = 0.0
    Total = 0.0
                  
    while True:
        earned = input("What is the grade earned? or type *exit* to proceed to the next section: ")
        if earned == 'exit':
            break
        earnedTotal+=float(earned)
        print(earnedTotal)

    while True:
        subTotal = input("What is the total of assignment? Enter the next... or type *exit* for the average grade: ")
        if subTotal == 'exit':
            break
        Total+=float(subTotal)
        print(Total)
    
    average = earnedTotal/Total
    
    print(f"The average of {earnedTotal}/{Total} is {average*100)", Grade(average))

ClassGrader()
```

Comment: Thank you much! I understand now. From what you've said... Class is kinda like house and function sorta like a room so I was calling to a room that's just floating outside. I see my many errors. It's been years since any attempt at coding. I remember much more from your answer so thank you. I made the usability on the user side better. Now to clean up the actual code. Thank you again!

Comment: A class is used when you have an object that needs to store state information -- when you need to remember stuff and use it later.  Here, you pass in an input (or not), and you get an output.  That is a function.